# Sketchfab API and Javascript alternate functions with only one button

Tags: javascript, html, api, button

im using the Sketchfab api and I want to alternate between two functions. I tried this, but it only works once. Thank you.

```
hidebutton.onclick =  function(){
  exterior = new Boolean (true);
  console.log(exterior);  
  if(exterior == true){
    api.hide(nodeTop);
    exterior = !exterior;
    console.log(exterior);
    if(exterior == false){
      hidebutton.onclick = function(){
        api.show(nodeTop);
        console.log('funcion else');
        exterior = true;
        console.log(exterior);
      } 
    };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use plain booleans (`true`) rather than the constructor (`new Boolean`).

You need to declare the boolean outside of the function so that its value is preserved between clicks:

```
let exterior = true;
hidebutton.onclick = function() {
  if (exterior) api.hide(nodeTop);
  else api.show(nodeTop);
  exterior = !exterior;
};
```

Even better, keep it self-contained so that only the click function has access to it (encapsulation is good - avoid polluting outer scopes):

```
hidebutton.onclick = (() => {
  let exterior = true;
  return () => {
    if (exterior) api.hide(nodeTop);
    else api.show(nodeTop);
    exterior = !exterior;
  };
})();
```